# How to take screenshots of webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `RenderRepaintBoundary` to take a screenshot, but just got the blank.

The code for the webview.

```dart
class _CustomWebViewState extends State<CustomWebView> {

  final GlobalKey screen = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: screen,
      child: InAppWebView(),
    );
  }
}
```

The code for the screenshot.

```dart
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = screen.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
```

Flutter throws an exception when executing `boundary.toImage()`:

```
[VERBOSE-2:platform_view_layer.cc(19)] Trying to embed a platform view but the PrerollContext does not support embedding
[VERBOSE-2:platform_view_layer.cc(28)] Trying to embed a platform view but the PaintContext does not support embedding
```

I have already set the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? Adding the embedded_views_preview to the info.plist didn't solve it for me either

Comment: me too , not help

Comment: Now I use the screenshot function of webview itself instead of flutter.